# Safari: Text in contenteditable div with no spaces does not wrap around image upon focus

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a div on the left half of (say) a dialog, and an image on the right half. The div and the image start at the same point vertically, but  the text is much longer than the image. I would like to for the text to be on the left side of the image, and once the image ends (vertically), I would like the text to occupy the complete width. Everything seems to work as expected as long as the text has spaces.

On Safari, once I click to edit the text and if the text has no spaces, the text jumps below the image as opposed to remaining to the left of the image. On Chrome things work as expected regardless of whether the text has spaces.

Is there any workaround to get the text to be on the left of the image when editing on Safari?

Simple JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/adeopura/jpu0yckL/. Expected behavior can be seen on Chrome (Version 62.0.3202.94) and the unexpected behavior can be seen on Safari (version 11.0.1). MAC OS version is 10.13.1. I would prefer if I do not have to modify the HTML structure and have a CSS only solution, but I am open to ideas.

HTML is:

```
<div class="image-desc-container">
<div class="image-container">
   <img width="120" class="image" src="http://www.ordnung-statt-chaos.de/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="textarea-container">
  <div contenteditable="true" class="my-input">Loremipsumdolorsitametconsetetursadipscingelitrseddiam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.image-desc-container{
  width: 250px; 
  min-height: 150px; 
  position: relative; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  background: #f7f7f7; 
  padding: 10px; 
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  display: block;
}

.image-container{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.my-input {
  min-height: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: block;
  user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  overflow: initial;
  white-space: pre-line;
  -webkit-nbsp-mode: normal;
  line-break: auto;
}
```

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle to showcase the issue in a better fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`white-space: pre` is working as expected on Safari but not on Chrome. You can declare two separate classes for Safari and Chrome and adjust them accordingly using Javascript.

Check out the updated fiddle. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/p9d62u45/3/)

I am using this snippet to check if the browser is `Safari`.

`var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);`

```js
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

document.getElementById("input").style.whiteSpace = isSafari ? "pre" : "pre-line";
```

```css
.image-desc-container{
  width: 250px; 
  min-height: 150px; 
  position: relative; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  background: #f7f7f7; 
  padding: 10px; 
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  display: block;
}

.image-container{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.my-input {
  min-height: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: block;
  user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  overflow: initial;
  -webkit-nbsp-mode: normal;
  line-break: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-desc-container">
    <div class="image-container">
       <img width="120" class="image" src="http://www.ordnung-statt-chaos.de/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="textarea-container">
      <div contenteditable="true" id="input" class="my-input">Loremipsumdolorsitametconsetetursadipscingelitrseddiam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working, please let me know do a little more testing and I will mark the answer and bounty shortly

Comment: Great! I updated the answer with some JS to detect if the browser is `Safari` or not. Please check.

Comment: I am using https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html#webkit to determine Safari. I could use what you are proposing as well.

Comment: It says I can only award this bounty in 16 hours, so I will do it tomorrow

Comment: Cool! I too will check out those hacks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your css added wrap-word property in #box class

```
#box { width: 250px; min-height: 150px; position: relative; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #f7f7f7; padding: 10px;word-wrap:break-word }

#box img { float: right; }
```

Comment: Thank you. The text going outside the container was something that I had addressed in the code but forgot to put it in the fiddle. The part about Safari not having the text wrap around the image is what I am concerned about, which the CSS you provided above does not solve.

Comment: I have tested it in Safari 5.1.7 version and text do wrap in it and working fine for me.
What exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: I am on Safari version 11.0.1 on the MAC. If you open the fiddle on Chrome, the text starts out to the left of the image. On Safari, the text starts out below the image. I am trying to have the behavior on Safari be the same as the behavior on Chrome.

Comment: Baseer haider - If you get a chance, please let me know if this works for you on Safari version 11.0.1